# ¿Cómo puedo programar el envío de un correo por código?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
/* Tengo la siguiente estructura */


                var subject     = "¡Feliz cumpleaños" ;
                var mailboxName = "Dev-Team";
                var me          = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
                var message     = "Felicidades... te mando un 
                                   abrazo....blablabla";

GmailApp.sendEmail("example@mail.com", subject, "", {htmlBody: message, name: mailboxName, from: me, cc:"example2@mail.com" , bcc: "example3@mail.com"});
Utilities.sleep(1000);
```

Necesito programar el envío desde hoy para el día de mañana a las 9:00 a.m 
¿Cómo lo hago desde código sin usar los Triggers o "activadores de proyecto activo"?
Agradeceré su apoyo colegas :)

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has buscado/investigado sobre lo que intentas hacer?

Comment: Me temo que no podrás hacerlo sin Triggers ya que no habría forma de hacer que se lance la acción de enviar el email por sí sola sin pasar por ellos. ¿Por qué no quieres usar Triggers, si existen para eso? ¿Prefieres dejar un camino real por una vereda? Existe una API de Tareas de Google (Tasks), pero por lo que aparece en la documentación no parece ser posible hacerlo por esa vía.

Comment: gracias por responder @A.Cedano, lo necesito enviar así porque tengo una función que envia una felicitación a una lista de usuarios y quiero crear otra función que envíe una felicitación a los mismos usuarios pero un día después con diferente mensaje, quiero hacer esto de manera automática

Comment: pero el detalle es que esa lista de usuarios o arreglo, cambia dia con dia,

Comment: El problema no es el *enviar* en sí, sino la forma de indicar que esa acción se ejecute de forma automática. Para eso necesitarás un Trigger sí o sí, no veo otra manera de hacer que una acción se ejecute sola. ¿Por qué no te usas una Google Sheet donde tengas todo lo que que hay que enviar (direcciones electrónicas, mensajes) y lanzas un trigger que lea esa hoja todos los días? Luego, la GoogleSheets la puedes llenar también de forma automatizada, para que cada día tenga precisamente las cosas que quieres enviar. Otra posibilidad sería con el propio GMail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Google Apps Script la forma de programar la ejecución de una secuencia de comandos (script) es por medio de los disparadores (triggers). Si no deseas usar los triggers deberás usar otra aplicación para hacer la programación y la API de ejecución de secuencias ([Apps Script Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/)) para llamar tu script.

Referencia

- [Triggers and Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)